# Determine y-coordinate of a 3rd point from 2 given points and an x-coordinate.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I'm working through the "Calculus 1" Coursera course (offline version, so no forums) and am struggling with the following question in the topic on Limits:

> Consider points $A=(-10,-4)$ and $C=(8,5)$. The point $B$ is on the line
>   passing through $A$ and $C$. The $x$-coordinate of $B$ is $-1$. Determine the
>   $y$-coordinate of $B$. Hint: Do not figure out the equation of the line to
>   solve this problem. Instead, use similar triangles to discover the
>   equation of a line yourself.

The solution given starts by saying:

> Draw your picture.
>   $$\frac{\overline{BD}}{\overline{DA}}=\frac{\overline{CE}}{\overline{EA}}$$

The picture I drew was [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yc209qdmtg) (not a promising start).

They go on to say:

> $\overline{DA} = x$-coordinate of $D$ minus $x$-coordinate of $A = -1 + 10= 9$
>
> $\overline{CE} = y$-coordinate of $C$ minus $y$-coordinate of $E = |5+4|=9$
>
> $\overline{EA} = x$-coordinate of $E$ minus $x$-coordinate of $A = 8 +
> 10=18$
>
> ...

I can see how we might derive a point $D$ as being some point with $-1$ as the $x$-coordinate, but I'm not following how they derive a point $E$.

I fear this is some basic geometry I've long-forgotten.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To put their hint in a different way: Try 'forgetting' about the coordinate system, and just describe the two given points in terms of their vertical/horizontal separations. How would you capture these geometrically?

Comment: draw two triangles ABD (small) and ACE(big), now overlap them such that D lies on AE, B is already on AC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation

$$\frac{\overline{BD}}{\overline{DA}}=\frac{\overline{CE}}{\overline{EA}}\tag{1}$$

holds because $\triangle ACE$ is [similar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_%28geometry%29#Similar_triangles) to $\triangle ABD$.

[image]

> I can see how we might derive a point D as being some point with -1 as the x-coordinate, but I'm not following how they derive a point E.

From the remaining information we conclude that the point $E(x_E,y_E)$ is the intersection of the horizontal line passing through $A$ with the vertical line passing through $C$, while the point $D(x_D,y_D) $ is the intersection of the horizontal line passing through $A$ with the vertical line passing through $B$ (see picture).

From $(1)$ and $\overline{DA} = 9$, $\overline{CE} =9$ and $\overline{EA} = 18$  we get  $\overline {BD}=9/2$. Since $\overline{BD}=y_B-y_D=y_B-y_A=y_B+4$, we find that the $y$-coordinate of $B$ is $y_B=1/2$.

Comment: Wow, I was really overthinking this. Given the lectures up to this point were all about limits, many having to do with limits of polynomials, I was assuming the line connecting A and C was a curve. Thus, I thought the reference to triangles was something more complex than it was. Thank you!

Comment: Of course now my question is: what does this exercise have to do with limits?

Comment: @Nick I don't know too. Perhaps it has indirectly something to do with a special limit, a derivative of a function.

Answer (score 0):

Relation with Limits:One thing that seems apparent is that since B lies right at the average of the x values of the triangles, then the triangles should be congruent. Therefore the y value of B should be the average of A and C y values. 1/2
And if you see other two questions in coursera you see the shift of y-coordinate of pointB as x-coordinate changes