# Using Similar Triangles to solve for the equation of a line

Tags: geometry

Consider points A=(−10,−4) and C=(8,5). The point B is on the line passing through A and C. The x-coordinate of B is −1. Determine the y-coordinate of the point B.

This question has been asked before. I am very much interested in a visual representation of solving this. It is part of a coursera self-paced no cert calculus course.

I have a very hard time equating the following solution pictorially with the use of similar triangles.

BD/DA = CE/EA where tow letter pairs are line segments.

DA= x-coordinate of D minus x-coordinate of A= −1+10=9
CE= y-coordinate of C minus y-coordinate of E= |5+4|=9
EA= x-coordinate of E minus x-coordinate of A= 8+10=18
so DB/9=918
Therefore, DB =9/2
Since B is above D, the y-coordinate of B is the y-coordinate of D plus the length of DB.
Thus the y-coordinate of B=−4+92=12

I am also fuzzy on Since B is above D, the y-coordinate of B is the y-coordinate of D plus the length of DB. What it was above.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: problem is solved at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919555/determine-y-coordinate-of-a-3rd-point-from-2-given-points-and-an-x-coordinate

Answer (score 0):

One thing that seems apparent is that since B lies right at the average of the x values of the triangles, then the triangles should be congruent.  Therefore the y value of B should be the average of A and C y values.  $\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

The last sentence of the fifth paragraph should have read,

> Thus the $y$-coordinate of B is $−4+\dfrac92=\dfrac12$.

which is the correct answer.